# Conditional probability sub-model so solve setting with a factor that has many levels

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, predictive-models, conditional-probability

I stumbled upon a post of the http://www.win-vector.com/ blog where they treat the problem when a factor with many levels occurs.

In my understanding instead of using the factor itself, they use the conditional probability of the outcome given the factor. Doing this they go from a factor to a continuous explanatory variable. I like this idea.

In the code in the [post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2012/07/modeling-trick-impact-coding-of-categorical-variables-with-many-levels/) they build a contingency table (for crimes counting yes/no per address) and then they mix it with the overall probability of a crime by

```
 levelcounts = table(x, y, useNA="always")
  condprobmodel = (levelcounts[,2]+p)/(levelcounts[,1]+levelcounts[,2]+1.0)
```

Thus they add $p$ the probability to the number of crimes (per address) and divide by the total number of occurrence of this address + 1.

What I see is that if the number of crimes is high, then this does not change much. If the number of crimes is 0, then the overall probabilit (p) is scaled down.

Doing "normal" conditional probability I don't get this expression

$$
P[\text{crime}|\text{address}] = P[\text{crime and address}]/P[\text{address}]
$$

but what does the value $p$ do here in an additive form?

Answer (score 1):

Reading another post of them [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/vtreat-designing-a-package-for-variable-treatment/)
I now think that the addition of $p$ in the numerator and $1$ in the denominator just makes sure that the impact score does not hit the boundaries of $[0,1]$. It is meant to smooth out the estimated conditional probability.